# angularJS scope.$watch whole object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to watch a whole object in angularJS ?

I created a plunker to show you what i mean:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QxLzbwKkJ5k50DiP8OP1

When i change the R G or B value the colors object won't fire a change event, only the R G or B value fires.
Can i fire a event myself so that it i know that the whole object changed ?

Besides the plunker here is the code:

```
function ColorObject()
{
    this.r = 0;
    this.g = 0;
    this.b = 0;

    this.c = 0;
    this.m = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.k = 0;

    this.hex = "#ff0000";
    this.oppositeHex = "#00ffff";
}

var chColorChanger = angular.module('chColorChanger',[]);

chColorChanger.controller('chColorChangerCtrl', function ($scope,$document,$element) 
{     
    $scope.colors = new ColorObject();
    $scope.gMessage = 0;
    $scope.message = 'scope initialized';
});

chColorChanger.directive('chColorValue',['$document',function($document) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('colors',function(newValue,oldValue){
               scope.gMessage++;
            });

            scope.$watch('colors.r', function (newValue,oldValue) {
                scope.message = 'r changed';
            });

            scope.$watch('colors.g', function (newValue,oldValue) {
                scope.message = 'g changed';
            });

            scope.$watch('colors.b', function (newValue,oldValue) {
                scope.message = 'b changed';
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to watch the whole object, you need to use deep watch. which needs third parameter to watch, as true...

```
        scope.$watch('colors',function(newValue,oldValue){
           scope.gMessage++;
        }, true);
```

Check this updated [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/OcOWgdPWKPnI83Iy3mIE?p=preview)